# Excel time comparison

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have given workers' start/end(coming to work and going out from work times) time in excel table. In 2nd table, I have given breakfast, lunch, dinner start/end times. How can I check worker can eat breakfast, lunch, dinner?

[image: Excel Table picture]

Comment: You want to know if a meal time falls within a worker's start/end time?

Comment: @Wolfie Yes, I want to check it.

Answer (score 2):

You would write in columns D, E, F (to check for breakfast, lunch, dinner, respectively):

`D2`: `=IF(AND($H$2>B2,$I$2<C2),"Yes","No")`

`E2`: `=IF(AND($H$3>B2,$I$3<C2),"Yes","No")`

`F2`: `=IF(AND($H$4>B2,$I$4<C2),"Yes","No")`

Then copy `D2:F2` and paste below.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I have to write all of them in 1 cell. By the way, If worker4 comes to work 1/01/2011 at 23:00 and goes to home 02/01/2011 at 12:00, his meal count should be written to 01/01/2011 not to 01/01/2011

Comment: "should be written to [date]" makes no sense, you have no dates in your data! You can use `&` to combine strings, and just put all three of Sancho's formulas into one (with more descriptive outputs). Please clarify your problem by editing your question, it's currently too broad and it seems you have other criteria / ambitions not described